# Speed of Firebase Node library vs REST

Tags: firebase

I'm currently building a [Koa](http://koajs.com) app with the [Firebase Node library](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html). Is there a speed difference between using that compared to [REST](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html)?

Answer (score 2):

This is something that would best be determined by some profiling or jsperf-style testing.

The simplest answer is that there would naturally be a difference, particularly at higher frequencies of transcations. The node.js SDK works over a socket connection, whereas the REST client would have the overhead of establishing and tearing down connections with each payload.

One helpful tool that can help narrow the gap in performance is to utilize HTTP 1.1's [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) feature. However, it's certainly not going to be comparable to web sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a web-socket real-time database provider, so it's much more faster than HTTP REST calls, that has a big overhead of creating a new connection for each call, so you can use this link below to have an idea:
http://blog.arungupta.me/2014/02/rest-vs-websocket-comparison-benchmarks/